# How to slice data from a column and sorting according to it in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here are 2 tables. The problem is i want department table sorting using score(in mapping table).

How to do it in mysql ?

```
Department _table
DeptId , Title , score
1, Physics , [{"StuId:Score"}, {2:6}, {1:9}]
2, Chemistry, [{"StuId:Score"}, {1:5}, {2:8}]

Student_table
StuId, Title
1 , John
2 , David
```

Expected Result for StuId =  1 in DESC order by score

```
DeptId , Title, score
1, Physics , 9
2, Chemistry, 5
```

Expected Result for StuId =  2 in DESC order by score

```
DeptId , Title, score
2, Chemistry, 8
1, Physics , 6
```

Comment: The department table looks as though the data is stored in some weird JSON format, is there any particular reason for this or should the database be designed properly?

Comment: The reason is not all student get score in all subject. There will be few. Should i use a new 3rd table to map ? I mean extra table to design with column (mapid, StuId, DeptId, score) 

or  is there any way to slice from JSON data and sort it ?

Note: The department table will contain a large number (may be around a million) of data but there will very less students (around 1K)

Comment: Normally you would have a third table as you say, with student ID, department ID (although this maybe should be an exam table - so you store their score against a particular exam/test rather than the department) and the score they achieved.

Comment: Alright. I supposed to try crazy things using the concept of noSQL. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you add that to the question - then that would help in understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want to extract from JSON - have a read of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths

Answer (score 0):

if you ask about the sql statement here is it you cat test in phpMyadmin
    select * from 'department' ORDER BY 'score' DESC
or you can show your code to farther help But for sorting we use order by

Comment: Not Really! There is JSON data in score field. I need to extract score rating according to student id and then sort it.